# Maximum number of unit vectors with bounded pairwise dot products

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vectors, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $t\in(0,\tfrac{1}{2})$. Upper bound $m$ such that there exist $v_1,...,v_m\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|v_i\|=1$ and $|v_i\cdot v_j|\le t$ for all $i\neq j$.

If $t=0$, $v_i\cdot v_j=0$, so $v_1,...,v_m$ are linearly independent, so $m\le n$. This is tight using the standard basis. I came up with nothing for $t>0$. I suppose you could bound the distance between $v_i$ and $v_j$, but I don't see how that's useful.

Comment: This should help https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson-Lindenstrauss_lemma

Comment: Do we linearly map $v_1,...,v_m$ to $\mathbb{R}^p$ for $p>8\log m/\epsilon^2$? If so, we seem to be in the same scenario. Previously $\|v_i-v_j\|^2\in[2-2t,2+2t]$. Now $\|f(v_i)-f(v_j)\|^2\in[(1-\epsilon)(2-2t),(1+\epsilon)(2+2t)]$. How does it help?

Comment: Oops, I read too fast. My link provides a lower bound. I'm not sure about upper bounds at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Here is a crude approach:

(1)  $|v_i-v_j|=\sqrt{2-2v_i\cdot v_j}\geq \sqrt{2-2t}$.

(2) The balls $B_{i}:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}: |x-v_i|< \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-2t}\}$, $1\leq i\leq m$ are disjoint subsets of $B_0:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: |x|< 1+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-2t}\}$, hence $\sum_{i=1}^{m}|B_i|\leq |B_0|$

(3) Since the volume of balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ scales like $r^n$, you may deduce that
$$
m(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-2t})^n\leq (1+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-2t})^n 
$$

or

$$
m\leq \left(\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-2t}}{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-2t}}\right)^n 
$$

As shown by the [Johnson--Lindenstrauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma), any upper bound must grow at least exponentially with respect to $n$ for fixed $t>0$.
An obvious flaw of the bound is that it doesn't recover (not even remotely so) the bound $m\leq n$ for $t=0$. For $t\to 1$ it becomes vacuous ($m\leq \infty$), as it should.